# Convert PDF to multipage TIFF file using ghostscript in Java

Tags: java, ghostscript

Download the Ghost libraries from [Ghost4j site](http://www.ghost4j.org/downloads.html.). Minimum jar required are ghost4j-1.0.0.jar, jna-3.3.0.jar, log4j-1.2.15.jar.
Also, you have to install the Ghostscript setup, which you can find from [ghostscript site](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) according to your windows bit.

Below is the code to convert the PDF to multipage TIFF.

```
public void PDFtoMultipageTIFFileByScript(String pdfFileLoc, String fileName, String tiffFileLoc) {
    try {
        Ghostscript gs = Ghostscript.getInstance();
        List<String> gsArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
        gsArgs.add("gswin64c.exe");
        gsArgs.add("-o");
        gsArgs.add(tiffFileLoc);
        gsArgs.add("-sDEVICE=tiffg4");
        gsArgs.add("-r600"); //Resolution.
        gsArgs.add(pdfFileLoc);
        //System.out.println("command running : " + gsArgs.toString());

        gs.initialize(gsArgs.toArray(new String[0]));
        gs.exit();
    } catch (GhostscriptException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule) {
        throw new RuntimeException(getMessage(ule.getMessage()));
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError ncdfe) {
        throw new RuntimeException(getMessage(ncdfe.getMessage()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

String getMessage(String message) {
    if (message.contains("library 'gs") || message.contains("ghost4j")) {
        return message + GS_INSTALL;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be an answer, not a question!

Comment: Yes I know, I wanted to upload this solution on StackOverflow. But don't know how to upload the solution. So by mistake, I uploaded in the question section.